# Showing $f(z)=h_x(z)-ih_y(z)$ is an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck on this question.

> Given that a real-valued function $h$ is a solution of the Laplace equation in an open set $U$ means that $h$ is twice continuously differentiable and satisfies $h_{xx}(z)+h_{yy}(z)=0$ for all $z \in U$.  Show that the function $f:U \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(z)=h_x(z)-ih_y(z)$ is an analytic function.

Since $h$ is twice differentiable on $U$, this shows us that $h_x$ and $h_{xx}$ exists for all $z \in U$ (same for $y$ derivatives).  Differences of analytic functions are still analytic.  Do these two facts prove that $f$ is analytic?

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Riemann Equations

Comment: This may sound silly, but of the components or of $f$?

Comment: Yes, components of $f$.

Comment: So, will it be something like $u_x=h_{xx}$ and $u_y=h_{xy}$...and so forth?

Comment: $v_x=-h_{yx}=-h_{xy}=-u_y$, and $v_y=-h_{yy}=h_{xx}=u_x$

Comment: Awesome, if you want to post your remark about the CR equations as the answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
 Cauchy-Riemann Equations:

$v_x=-h_{yx}=-h_{xy}=-u_y$, and $v_y=-h_{yy}=h_{xx}=u_x$

Comment: Would I apply the C-R equations twice?

Comment: C-R equations are a pair of equations: $u_x=v_y, u_y=-v_x$ both need to be shown to prove that $f=u+iv$ is analytic.